# TwoWay focus binding in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this custom binding that updates an observable with the data for the focused child element of the element that is is applied to:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selected =
  init: (element, valueAccessor) ->
    receiver = valueAccessor()
    $(element).focusin((event) ->
      data = ko.dataFor(event.target)
      receiver(data)
    )
```

This works better than the standard `hasFocus` binding for the use case where I want some other part of the page to show information about the focused item:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items, selected: selectedItem">
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a></li>
</ul>
<p data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    Selected: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</p>
```

Now I want to make this a two-way binding, so that I can change `selectedItem` from my script code, and make the correct list element focused with `$.focus()`. Any ideas how to extend the binding to work in both ways?

I realize that I may need to use the "control descendant bindings" approach, and not be able to apply the binding to the same element as the `foreach` binding, but that's fine. The problem I have is that the child element doesn't seem to be bound when the update function is called (`dataFor` returns undefined).

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of where you are upto and a little more info on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ptWxF/2/ It doesn't work very well in a regular browser, but this is for a platform with spatial navigation, where the focus is important.

Comment: Another update, with some styling http://jsfiddle.net/ptWxF/3/

Comment: You will need to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f8GTt/. But I'm sure that this can be do with the built in hasFocus binding I just need to create a new example for that, although I'm not sure whether that would be nicer than your current solution...

Comment: @nemesv Yes, that is exactly what I've come up with. And yes it can be done with hasFocus, but we're probably going to do this everywhere, which is why I want to have it completely contained in a custom binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through the descendant elements in your `update` function and check which element to focus using the `ko.dataFor`:

```
update: (element, valueAccessor) ->
    receiver = valueAccessor()
    item = receiver()
    $(element).find("*").each((index, elem) ->      
      if (item == ko.dataFor(elem))
        $(elem).focus()
    )
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8GTt/1/).

Comment: There are potential issues, like finding an element that corresponds to the item, but is not focusable, hidden etc, but the general idea works. I was hoping that knockout had something that worked opposite of dataFor, but I think that is not possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have decided to create a custom binding for finding out a selected item in a collection and storing it in an observable?

You can simply capture an event and find out the selected item:

```
var data = [
    { "Id" : 0, "Name" : "Item0" },
    { "Id" : 1, "Name" : "Item1" },
    { "Id" : 2, "Name" : "Item2" },
    { "Id" : 3, "Name" : "Item3" },
    { "Id" : 4, "Name" : "Item4" },
    { "Id" : 5, "Name" : "Item5" },
    { "Id" : 6, "Name" : "Item6" },
    { "Id" : 7, "Name" : "Item7" }
]

function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.selectItem = function(item){
        self.selectedItem(item);
    }
    self.select3rd = function(){
        self.selectedItem(self.items()[2]);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: Name, event: { focus : $parent.selectItem }, attr: { 'tabindex' : $index }"></a></li>
</ul>

<p>Selected item: <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedItem)"></span></p>

<button data-bind="click: select3rd">Select 3rd item</button>
```

[And the fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyTHv/)

Comment: The whole point is to control and monitor the focus indicator of the browser, not to handle mouse events.

Comment: updated to not use mouse events. all non webkit browsers fire focus when an anchor is clicked but webkit needs tabindex to activate that (I think it's a known bug)

Comment: If you like you can also change the tabindex to be $index + 1 so the first one's tabindex is not zero

Comment: Still, this is just a one-way binding. The question was specifically about how to make it two-way. That is, how to set focus to the element when the selectedItem observer is changed in select3rd.

Comment: The hasFocus binding provided by knockout has this two-way functionality, but it uses a separate "isSelected" observable for each item, I want to do the same with the selectedItem observable.